# How to add and create roles in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have searched around a lot to try and find a way to create roles in discord.py, but I haven't found anything. I would like to be able to use a command to create and/or add roles to a user. My code is:

```py
await client.create_role(message.author)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To create roles,

For the rewrite branch:

```
guild = ctx.guild
await guild.create_role(name="role name")
```

to add color, just add `colour=discord.Colour(0xffffff)` as an option in create_role, and replace `ffffff` with the hex code for the color. To add permissions to the role, include `permissions=discord.Permissions(permissions=<permission value>)`

For the async branch:

```
author = ctx.message.author
await client.create_role(author.server, name="role name")
```

to add color (and probably permissions), just do the same as you would for the rewrite branch.

Now, if you want to add roles to a user,

For the rewrite branch:

```
role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="role to add name")
user = ctx.message.author
await user.add_roles(role)
```

For the async branch:

```
user = ctx.message.author
role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="role to add name")
await client.add_roles(user, role)
```

To see which branch you have, do `print(discord._version)`. If it says 1.0.0a, you have the rewrite branch. If it says 0.16.2 or a lower number, you have the async branch. To calculate permission values, you can use [this](https://discordapi.com/permissions.html) website

note: Discord.py is currently at 1.6

Comment: How can I add a specific permission?