# How to give someone a role in the Discord.py Rewrite

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm creating a bot for my discord server. And when a user says a specific command the bot will give them a role

I've already tried finding other codes in the other stackoverflow questions and looked at the the Discord.Py Rewrite Documentation. Also for videos, they are all not discord.py rewrite

```py
@bot.command()
async def recruitme(ctx):
    user = ctx.message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="Recruit")
    await user.guild.roles(role)
```

I expect that I can learn how to code that a bot gives a role.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216914/how-to-add-and-create-roles-in-discord-py) covers how to create and add roles.

Comment: @Anu6is what do you mean?

Comment: @Anu6is But its not working though.....

Comment: @Anu6is wait nvm. I've foind the solution because of you. Thank you

Comment: lol, no problem

Answer (score 2):

```
@client.command()
    async def role(ctx, member:discord.Member, role: discord.Role): #pass user and role
        if role in member.roles: #checks all roles the member has
            await member.remove_roles(role) #removes the role
        else:
            await member.add_roles(role) #adds the role
```

In this, the code first checks for the specified role in all roles the member has. It adds the role if it doesn't exist and removes it if it already exists.

Comment: Hope It will solve issue but please add explanation of your code with it so user will get perfect understanding which he/she really wants.

Comment: Hi! I've added comments and also an explanation. Hope it will help. Thanks,