# How do you create a new role in discord.py?

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

I have the following function in my bot to create x empty new roles (for this example I'll make it all the bot does):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

CLIENT = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@CLIENT.event
async def on_ready():
    """triggers when bot is running"""
    print("Bot online")

@CLIENT.command(pass_context=True)
async def role(ctx, x=1):
    """creates x roles"""
    guild = ctx.guild
    for i in range(x):
        await guild.create_role(name="new role")
    print("created " + str(x) + " roles")

CLIENT.run("token")
```

The bot doesn't create the new roles or print out the message. (no output to the console at all, its as if the function had just said pass) What did I do wrong?

Comment: This maybe a duplicate from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216914/how-to-add-and-create-roles-in-discord-py)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add and create roles in discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216914/how-to-add-and-create-roles-in-discord-py)

Comment: Your code should work except you are trying to make the same role over and over again. Try to make the rule unique maybe use date and time and user author.

Answer (score 0):

`ctx.guild` is `None` because you didn't enable `intents.guilds` to fix that you need to enable some basic intents, also you should typehint the `x` arg so it's converted to an integer.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()

CLIENT = commands.Bot(..., intents=intents)
```

```py
@CLIENT.command()
async def role(ctx, x: int=1):
    for i in range(x):
        await ctx.guild.create_role(f'new role {i}')

    print(f"Created {x} roles")
```